# reCAPTCHA - Incorrect key type

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3

I want to secure the form on my website with a reCAPTCHA script. After adding the script and this window is displayed and in it an error - "Information for the website owner - we detected an Error: incorrect key type". I will add that the domain is correctly configured and added in the appropriate section of reCAPTCHA. This is a page written on Jekyll and here may be a problem. For the script to work there correctly you need an encrypted private key - and there may be a problem. I tried to generate the key several times but nothing helped - still the same error. I created new V3 keys and checked. But that too didnt work. Any idea on how to solve this problem?

My code:

```html
... form ...
<input type="hidden" name="options[reCaptcha][siteKey]" value="6LfF_7AZAAAAAK796nWHg-K4DkjG_-pnlfEH7Ch0">
<input type="hidden" name="options[reCaptcha][secret]" value="KX02DlLiKdqKkMkyAThrIVhjP9zydIZ/KC0copPjpdkkA1cX+zy5loEpg+c618R5kZMKXlelpN/2GDItQWNy4alUGQCtP8k8GTioTtZVmuNXal5sbP1OPkXFKof+6auTz5cfeFs2XRkrQlduNAw/Bc0TB/7RiZNOjMNGBSmbKWc=">
<fieldset class="security">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LfF_7AZAAAAAK796nWHg-K4DkjG_-pnlfEH7Ch0"></div>
</fieldset>
... end form ...
<script type="text/javascript">
var onload = function() {
grecaptcha.render('html_element', {
'sitekey' : '6LfF_7AZAAAAAK796nWHg-K4DkjG_-pnlfEH7Ch0',
'theme' : 'dark'
});
};
</script>
<script async src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onload"></script>
```

(Old keys - i generated new)

[Link to the page](https://igorkowalczyk.github.io/blog/?ref=stack)

[Link to the repository](https://github.com/igorkowalczyk/blog)

(The form is in every post)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm solved the problem - now I using the reCAPTCHA v2 - Checkbox. Change of the version solved the problem. Generating new keys for v2 version solved this problem. Captcha displays and works correctly.